# VBA Send Keys - Populate Third Party Dialog Box

Tags: vba

I'm trying use SendKeys in VBA (Word 2010) to populate a dialog box for some third party fax software. The code below brings up the fax dialog box and it has focus with the cursor blinking in the field where I want to send the data. But the data actually gets sent to the Word document (or the code editor -- wherever the sub is called from). How can I prevent this and populate the dialog box?

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub RightFax()

With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrintSetup)
    .Printer = "RightFax Fax Printer"
    .DoNotSetAsSysDefault = True
    .Execute
End With

SendKeys "{Enter}"

        Sleep 500                 'test - prints in word doc or code editor
            SendKeys "TEST AAA"
        Sleep 500

With Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint)
    .Show
End With

        Sleep 500                 'test - prints in word doc or code editor
            SendKeys "TEST BBB"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the third party fax software have a DLL you could set a reference to? `SendKeys` is almost always hard to use and is somewhat of a last resort.  In any event -- without knowing something about this third party software I don't see how anybody could answer the question.

Comment: Trying SendKeys as thought would be a simple solution for myself and a few other users. Started to look at other options per your note and found there are library references in editor for RightFax API etc. which  can be added --  but seem beyond my abilities. Will research further along this line. Thanks

Comment: These third party APIs are not always well-documented, but sometimes the company's website will contain information for developers. Also, depending on how good the company's customer service is they might be willing to answer some questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I am with B. Cap on this SendKeys is evil and almost never works. The good new is that you have a DLL file that you can use for development. Look into the following links: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxxhT7DHC0s , http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/third-party-products/17461-sending-fax-using-rightfax.html , http://rightfaxapi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/COM_Reference_Guide_v8.5.pdf , http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1715908 I hope this helps.